problema de posiciones
este es un ejercicio donde habia tres consignas, sacar el promedio de los negativos ingresados en orden par, mostrar el mayor de los positivos y su posicion y por ultimo mostrar la cantidad de valores que son comprendidos entre 120 y 180, y este es el codigo que hice, pero tengo un problema con el segundo punto de la tarea, ya que cuando en consola salta la posicion no es correcta, es el total de los positivos y no su posicion, queria saber como se podria arreglar.
esta escrito en python
dato = int(input("ingresa un numero:"))
contar = 0 
sumNeg = 0
contNeg = 0
ContRango = 0
# contPos = 0
may = 0
posicion = 0
prom = 0

while dato != 0:
    contar += 1
    
#promedio de negativos    
    if dato < 0:
        if contar % 2 == 0:
            sumNeg += dato
            contNeg += 1
            
#mayor positivos y su posicion            
    if dato > 0:
        posicion += 1
        if posicion == 1:
            may = dato
            posicion = posicion
    if dato > may:
        may = dato
        posicion = posicion
        
#cant de valores entre esos rangos        
    if dato > 120 and dato < 180:
        ContRango += 1
        
    dato = int(input("ingresar dato: "))
    
if contNeg > 0:
    prom = sumNeg / contNeg
else:
    print("no hay negativos")
      

print(f"el promedio de los negativos es: {prom}")    
print(f"la cantidad de valores es: {ContRango}")
print(f"el mayor positivo es: {may} y la posicion es {posicion}")


Hay varios problemas en tu código.

la variable posicion

solo se incrementa si el número es positivo, pero al final la usas para indicar la posición del número mayor entre todos los ingresados.
la sentencia posicion = posicion que aparece dos veces, realmente no hace nada, pues va a asignar a la variable el mismo valor que ya tiene. Lo que quieres hacer en ese caso es almacenar la posición en la que fue ingresado el valor, pero la sentencia correcta sería posicion = contar (más adelante hablaremos sobre el nombre de las variables).
la secuencia de sentencias if dato > 0/if posicion == 1 me parece innecesaria, basta con el if que está más abajo para saber que el dato ingresado es mayor que el almacenado en la variable may y recordar el índice en el que se ingresó.


mostrar la cantidad de valores que son comprendidos entre 120 y 180, a mi entender el rango incluye los valores inicial y final, por lo que la expresión para incrementar el contador es incorrecta:
if dato > 120 and dato < 180:

en realidad debería ser:
if dato >= 120 and dato <= 180:


Inconsistencia de los mensajes, en el primer input dices input("ingresa un numero:"), y de allí en adelante input("ingresar dato: "). Esto es porque no estás siguiendo el principio dry. Creo que podrías lograr tener una única sentencia de pedido del dato con una estructura así:
dato = -1
while dato != 0:
    dato = int(input("Ingresar dato: "))
    # el resto del proceso del dato

Si bien hace necesario declarar e inicializar la variable antes del ciclo, considero que es más limpio y mantiene la consistencia, en tu código, de todas  maneras declaras la variable y la inicializas con el valor ingresado por el usuario.

Nombres de variables: Este es un tema profundo, considero que hay que aprender a elegir los nombres de variables para que el código sea legible. Esto implica dar un nombre que sea claro, por ejemplo:

Usar sustantivos y no verbos. contar, en tu código, no deja claro que almacena. Tiene el problema de ser un verbo, lo cual resulta ya de entrada confuso, pues da idea de una acción (los métodos y rutinas debieran usar verbos para sus nombres, pero no las variables). Es mejor, entonces, usar contador, que contar.

Usar palabras compuestas si hace falta. Aquí contador sería un buen nombre de variable si el programa o rutina solo cuenta una cosa, pero si hay varias cosas que contar, es mejor añadir palabras, como contadorPositivos o contadorEnRango, para evitar confusiones.

Abreviaturas: Es válido usar abreviaturas solo si son 100% claras para cualquier persona que vaya a leer el código. Es mil veces preferible usar mayor en lugar de may, pues lar leer el código:
if dato > mayor:

Deja claro su cometido, mientras que
if dato > may:

Probablemente requiera un vistazo a los alrededores para comprender mejor de que se trata. Es increíble como algo tan simple puede mejorar la comprensión del código, no solo para vos, sino para tu profesor, en este caso, pero en la vida profesional, para todo tu equipo de trabajo.
Siguiendo estos consejos, yo usaría variables tales como:
sumaNegativos = 0.0
contadorNegativos = 0
contadorEnRango = 0
mayor = 0
indiceMayor = 0
promedioNegativos = 0
indice = 0
dato = -1






El error está en que tu variable posicion debería indicar el índice del número par mayor ingresado, solo necesitas establecer posición al valor de contador si se cumple en tu segundo if:
# mayor positivos y su posicion            
if dato > may:
    may = dato
    posicion = contador

Ten en cuenta que si el entero mayor se repite, esto solo mostraría la poción de su primera aparición (o la última si cambias el > por >=). Si debieras mostrarlas todas necesitarías usar un contenedor como una lista para almacenarlas.
Dicho esto y agregando algunas consideraciones propias a la buena respuesta de @jachguate:

Si no vas a validar la entrada y te permiten usarlo, puedes hacer uso del operador morsa en el while:
while (dato := int(input("Ingresa un numero: "))) != 0:


Para validar los número dentro del rango, Python permite hacer esto:
if 120 < dato < 180:

Si el rango no incluye 120 y 180 o si los incluye (el ejercicio no parece aclararlo explícitamente):
if 120 <= dato <= 180:

Es más legible en mi opinión, menos propenso a cometer fallos y más eficiente.

En vez de usar un segundo if encadenado para comprobar si el número es positivo, usa un else asociado al primer if. Si el número no es 0 (descartado por el condicional del while) ni negativo (descartado por el primer condicional) ha de ser positivo. Usar un if en este caso es ineficiente ya que obligas al intérprete a evaluar un condicional cuando ya sabes que si no se cumple el primero va a ser cierto siempre.

En Python por convención, las variables se nombran usando snake_case, es decir, solo minúsculas separando palabras con guinos bajos. Es solo una convención, no es incorrecto no hacerlo, pero te recomiendo seguirla, ayuda a la legibilidad del código (concepto fundamental en este lenguaje) por parte de otros desarrolladores familiarizados con Python. Lectura recomendada: PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code


Con todo ello, el código quedaría algo así:
contador = 0
mayor_positivo = 0
indice_mayor_positivo = 0
suma_negativos = 0
contador_negativos = 0
contador_en_rango = 0

while (dato := int(input("Ingresa un numero: "))) != 0:
    contador += 1

    if dato < 0:
        if contador % 2 == 0:
            suma_negativos += dato
            contador_negativos += 1
    else:
        if dato > mayor_positivo:
            mayor_positivo = dato
            indice_mayor_positivo = contador

    if 120 <= dato <= 180:
        contador_en_rango += 1

Como comentaba previamente, quizás sería recomendable validar la entrada del usuario, lo cual puedes hacer manejando la excepción generada por int() si el usuario ingresa algo que no es un entero:
dato = -1
while dato != 0:
    try:
        dato = int(input("Ingresa un numero: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("No ha ingresado un entero...")
        continue

Puedes decidir si volver a pedir un número (continue) o terminar el ciclo y mostrar los resultados con los datos previos ingresados (break).
